# Use react native in an existing Android Native app?

Tags: react-native

I am new to React and React native.

Can I use React native instead of web view in an android app. Is it possible?

Currently webview loads a web page slow as compared to iOs webview.

So I am thinking of creating page with React Native and use it in the android native app.

Anyone who has done like this, please let me know if it's possible.

Thanks in Advance

---

### UPDATE

Will this help https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html ?

Comment: perhaps you are talking about `react` and not `react-native`

Comment: Actually, I have a confusion regarding React Native, the web page that I am currently opening  in android web view is in React but page load is slow. I wanted to know if I create same page in react native, would it be possible for android to use it..Kind of like Jsonette..Not sure if I have put my question correctly here, so sorry for any typo

Comment: I think I am trying to do https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html this

Answer (score 0):

That's two different things.

1) Using cordova or phonegap or webview

It means that you will write web application (in react for example), than using cordova, phone gap, or your custom implementation, that will build Android native application. This app will contain one screen/activity that will contain webview and in this webview will run your app as normal web base app .. you can imagine this as height level that you build your custom native browser and in it will run web app as normal webpage.

2) In react native you can imagine in height level that you will be build native application app instead writing this in JAVA or Objective C you are using JavaScript and React ...

But this is very height level overview :-)

Comment: Will this help https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between React and React Native when you are coding, specially the tags.

For example: If you wanted to output a text
In React you could use:

```
render(
    return (<h1> Hello, World </h1>);
);
```

In React native you could use:

```
render(
    return (<Text>Hello, World</Text>);
);
```

So, you could actually carry part of your code from React to React Native (fetchs and other business logic) , but you would need to change some part of it (specially the render method).